# Displaying the search module on one page only

Tags: search, joomla, joomla3.2

I have installed my smart search module which is working fine, I want to only have this on my page 'blog' which - as you might have guessed - is a category blog.
I have tried the following things:

1. Only assign on the pages selected, here I selected blog
2. On all pages except those selected, here I selected everything apart from blog.
3. Included the search module in my category description, this worked, however, then I had two search bars instead of one. Is there a way to do this without the search bar appearing twice?

The problem is that the search bar does not only show up on the category blog site, but also on all the blog posts. How can I make sure that it only shows up on the blog page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the article is accessible from the `Category Blog` menu item, i.e. it appears in articles listed in the blog it will inherit the module positions of the `Blog` menu item. Thats how stock standard Joomla generally works. *At least I think that's the way it works out of the box.*

The reason I'm unsure is that we've been using the [Advanced Module Manager](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager)([on the JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/modules-management/10307)) extension (free and paid versions available) for nearly as long as we've been using Joomla. Using that I know we can specify whether a module appears on child items.